# Mocking Func<Tin,Tout>

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I have some use cases where I pass Funcs to some methods. What I'm trying to do is create an extension or helper with Moq that allows my tests to easily create functions. The goal of this helper is

1. Easy to define a function with an expected input and a fixed output
2. Test should fail if function is not invoked
3. Test should fail if function is invoked with wrong input
4. Using `It.IsAny<TInput>()` should work as in any mock

I got most of what I wanted, but item 4 is eluding me. Here's the extension and tests with the elusive failing test I don't understand

```
public static Func<TIn, TOut> FixedFunc<TIn, TOut>(this MockRepository repo, TIn expectedInput, TOut fixedOutput)
{
    var verifier = repo.Create<IInvokable<TIn, TOut>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    verifier.Setup(m => m.Invoke(expectedInput))
        .Returns(fixedOutput);

    return input => verifier.Object.Invoke(input);
}

public static Func<TIn, TOut> FixedFunc<TIn, TOut>(this MockRepository repo, TOut fixedOutput)
{
    var verifier = repo.Create<IInvokable<TIn, TOut>>(MockBehavior.Strict);

    verifier.Setup(m => m.Invoke(It.IsAny<TIn>()))
        .Returns(fixedOutput);

    return input => verifier.Object.Invoke(input);
}

public interface IInvokable<TIn, TOut>
{
    TOut Invoke(TIn input);
}
```

and here the tests

```
[Fact] // succeeds
public void MockFunc_SameObject_RetursResult()
{
    var expectedInput= new object();
    var expectedOutput = 2;

    var repo = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var function = repo.FixedFunc(exptecedInput, expectedOutput);

    var output = function(expectedInput);
    Assert.Equal(expectedOutput, output);

    repo.VerifyAll();
}

[Fact]
// Fails with the following exception:
// "Moq.MockException: IInvokable`2.Invoke(object) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
// All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup."
public void MockFunc_IsAny_RetursResult()
{
    var exptecedInput = new object();
    var expectedOutput = 2;

    var repo = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var function = repo.FixedFunc(It.IsAny<object>(), expectedOutput);

    var output = function(exptecedInput);
    Assert.Equal(expectedOutput, output);

    repo.VerifyAll();
}

[Fact] // succeeds
public void MockFunc_WithAny_RetursResult()
{
    var expectedOutput = 2;

    var repo = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var function = repo.FixedFunc<object, int>(expectedOutput);

    var output = function(new object());
    Assert.Equal(expectedOutput, output);

    repo.VerifyAll();
}
```

I don't understand how using `It.IsAny` works for FixedFunc`<TOut`> but not for FixedFunc`<TIn, TOut`>

Answer (score 0):

Notice one thing, if you evaluate `It.Any<object>()` the result will be `null`. In the case of the `Func<TIn, TOut>` you are effectively creating setup for:

```
verifier.Setup(m => m.Invoke(null)).Returns(fixedOutput);
```

and then invoking it with `var exptecedInput = new object();`. During `VerifyAll` when `moq` tries to evaluate and match arguments it cannot do that because `null != new object()`.

---

You either want to invoke method also with `It.Any<object>()` or to re-design an extension to pass `Expression` and register setup with `Expression` instead of particular object.

```
[Fact] // This will pass
public void MockFunc_IsAny_RetursResult()
{
    var expectedOutput = 2;

    var repo = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var function = repo.FixedFunc(It.IsAny<object>(), expectedOutput);

    var output = function(It.IsAny<object>());

    Assert.Equal(expectedOutput, output);
    repo.VerifyAll();
}
```

Comment: Well, using It.IsAny<object> in the invocation would kill the purpose of the thing. I saw how It.IsAny<T>() will return default(T), but why does it work when I use It.IsAny while in the same context as the setup call and not when I pass It.IsAny as an argument? I even tried passing It.IsAny<string> (as a Func<TIn>) and invoke it during the setup but that also failed. Passing in an expression makes me lose all easy setup...any other ideas?

Comment: @MarcelBatista I agree passing `It.IsAny` doesn't make sense it was just for the sake of explanation. It works because if you provide it in a setup `It.IsAny` will be captured as expression which can be later on evaluated by `moq`. If you pass it as an argument then you lose expression but send only the value which is `default(object)`, `moq` then has no idea what was the original expression. You somehow need to send that expression, I think it is not possible way you are trying as you effectively creating the setup with one value and then verifying it with another...